# Frida - Hooking android method with unicode

Tags: javascript, android, frida

I need an expert for frida with android unicode methods.

There exists a method with an unicode name:

Example:

```
o.ɤ -> u\0264
```

Is there a way to hook methods with unicode or exists some documentation about hooking unicode methods ?

Comment: What have you tried so far - what worked what failed (edit and update your question)? JavaScript is also capable of Unicode, therefore it should be possible to also hook such methods.

Comment: https://github.com/frida/frida/issues/806